# SCSS REM MEDIA QUERIES

Tags: css, scss, responsive

В декстопе размер шрифта по дефаулту 16px. Сейчас занимаюсь адаптивом, вопросы следующие:
1. Нужно ли для различных устройств (смартфон,планшет)выставлять font-size у html,body к примеру 12-14px ?
2. Если нужно выставлять, но верно ли я понимаю что все REM'ы должны быть по отношению к родительскому фонт сайзу?
Ну к примеру в планшете родительский фонт сайз 14px, а для заголовка нужен размер 12пх, то указывать 0.857142857rem (12/14). Верно?
и какие вообще бест практики?

Answer (score 0):

1. Это исключительно на вкус дизайнера. Если на смартфоне слишком мелко, можете увеличить шрифт, если слишком крупно - уменьшить. Можете не трогать вообще. При этом удобство пользователя должно быть приоритетнее вкуса дизайнера, как бы дизайнер не доказывал обратное.
2. REM'ы НЕ ДОЛЖНЫ считаться относительно РОДИТЕЛЬСКОГО размера шрифта. Это EM'ы как раз так считаются. А REM'ы считаются относительно размера шрифта корневого элемента в DOM ("rem" = "root em"), то бишь, элемента `<html>`.
3. Если вам нужно в пикселях, выставляйте лучше в пикселях. Если нужно в `rem`, то верно. Хотя вместо жутких дробей можно использовать выражения: `font-size:calc(12rem / 14)`
4. Бест практики - а) овладеть всеми инструментами и применять их по ситуации и б) не использовать смесь английских и русских слов в одном словосочетании.